# Symfony CollectionType regards deletion+creation as a modification of an item

Tags: php, forms, doctrine-orm, symfony

I have a Symfony `OrderType` form attached to an **`Order`** object. This `Order` object has an `items` property which contains an `ArrayCollection` of **`OrderItem`** objects. These `OrderItem` objects each contain `product` and `quantity` properties. The `product` property is linked to a `Product` object. Each `OrderItem` is associated to an `OrderItemType` which is part of the `CollectionType` associated to the `Order` `items` property.

To make a long story short, here is the code (very simplified, with minimal properties and no doctrine annotations):

**Please note that everything basically works, I'm not looking for an error in this code :)**

### Order class

```
class Order {
    private $id;
    private $items;// ArrayCollection of OrderItem
}
```

### Order item class

```
class OrderItem {
    private $id;
    private $product;// Product object
    private $quantity;// int
}
```

### Order form

```
class OrderType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('items', CollectionType::class, array(
                'by_reference' => false,
                'entry_type'   => OrderItemType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true
            ));
    }
}
```

### Order item form

```
class OrderItemType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('product', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Product',
                'choice_label' => 'id'
            ))
            ->add('quantity', NumberType::class)
    }
}
```

Of course, the user can add and delete lines in an order which creates, edits and removes lines appropriately. Well almost...

If I remove the last line of the order and create a new line, Symfony thinks that the new line is actually a modification of the old one. Of course, there is no way for Symfony to know that this line is not the old one.

So I added an `id` field to my `OrderItemType`. But of course, Symfony cannot set the `id` on submit because there is no `setId` method in `OrderItem` (and that's normal because setting the `id` of an object manually is a bad idea).

Well that's where I'm stuck. I guess I could set the `id` field as `mapped: false` and implement custom logic on the controller to get rid of the old item that was deleted when its `id` does not appear in the posted values and create a new `OrderItem` for the item that has an empty `id`, but this seems like ugly hacking to me and I wonder if I'm not completely missing something as this looks like a very basic problem.

So does Symfony have a built-in way to recognize the difference between **deletion+creation** and **edition** in a `CollectionType` form? Am I completely missing something? Is the cake a lie?

## Edit

I know that my code is not complete, but I want to focus on the problem at hand. To put in another way:

1. The user creates two lines in the order for a client that wants 3 productA and 2 productB.
2. The user saves the order (Symfony creates 2 `OrderItem` objects with ID 1 and 2 in the database)
3. The client calls again and wants 5 productC instead of the 2 productB.
4. The user deletes line 2 (2 productB) and adds a new line (5 productC).

Here, Symfony changes the `OrderItem` with ID #2 by assigning the new product (productC) and quantity (5). But I would like Symfony to delete `OrderItem` #2 and create a new `OrderItem` with ID 3.

I hope that's a little bit more clear.

Comment: Note: You have `private $quantity;// float`, but a quantity "can't" be a float!!!

Comment: OK, now that's an `int`. I can make it a `string` or an `array`, that won't change anything to my problem, will it?

Comment: This is old, but Google brought me here; might help others, too. The solution is an indexed association, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64775433/symfony-collectiontype-update-entities

Answer (score 0):

I know you haven't added your Doctrine annotations yet, but it's related to the Id problem you are describing. Normally you auto generate an ID, so there is no 'setter', but there is a 'getter'.

So you would have something like this:

```
class OrderItem {
...
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="order_item_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $order_item_id;
```

Yes, your $quantity value should be an 'int', but it doesn't really matter. I'm just making you aware that you can't have half a quantity.

Comment: Sorry, but it has nothing to do with it. My code is several thousands of lines long and has been working for 4 months very well (except for the problem in my question). I just wrote this **very** simplified version to accompany the question.
Adding an `id` field seems like a wrong use of the `CollectionType` field.

Comment: You don't show enough of your code for anyone to give a good answer. You may want to repost a different question that is well thought out. I was only trying to help you. Also, if your code is thousands of lines long, then it doesn't seem to conform to the Symfony MVC best practices.

Comment: Sorry, I got a little carried away. I reexplained my problem in an edit to my question. I hope that explains it better.