# Symfony CollectionType update Entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I can't believe this hasn't come up for other people, but I'm unable to find a solution.

Let's say I have two entity types, A and B with a one-to-many relationship. A has a collection of Bs.

The form for A has a `CollectionType` for the Bs, with a custom `entry_type` for B, `allow_add` and `allow_delete` set to `true`. When the form is created/populated/rendered, the Bs' fields are identified by their index in the collection. When the form is posted back, the fields are mapped back onto the B entities according to the index again.

What if the database in the mean time decided to return the Bs in a different order? Then the values get swapped around on the Bs! I can't have that, as other entities will reference the Bs and now they've changed their meaning!

Even if the database doesn't change the order, the same issue appears when a B is deleted: The fields get shifted through the Bs and a different one deleted! (Ok, I'm not a 100% certain this happens, as there's a gap then in the numbering of the posted fields.) I've found this similar question where it does happen when another one is created ([Symfony CollectionType regards deletion+creation as a modification of an item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38333413/symfony-collectiontype-regards-deletioncreation-as-a-modification-of-an-item)), but that sort of drifted from the issue and there's no usable answer.

**How do I make sure the form is updating the entities the user actually edited?**

I already tried to render the Bs' IDs as a `HiddenType`, but then the form rightfully complains that the ID has no setter. It would probably force an ID on the wrong B anyways and Doctrine doesn't like that. I suppose I could add the Bs as unmapped and copy the values over to the correct objects manually, but that would defeat a good chunk of Symfony's form system.

I've used `CollectionType` before, but not for entities that are referenced elsewhere. I would then delete all of the previous entities and create the collection anew from the posted data. But I can't do that now, can I?

Comment: If I care about references staying consistent, I use EntityType, which will identify entries by their *id*. I don't edit related *entities* via collectiontype if I care about referential consistency, and I would suggest not to do that, and instead use js-"magic", to specifically edit related entities in a separated form and update only that entity via ajax or something.

Comment: @Jakumi `EntityType` doesn't allow editing the contained entities, so that doesn't work here
@msg you assumed right. `indexBy="id"` identifies the form fields by the B's ID and updates the right objects when posted back! It even removes entities that the user deleted from the collection (doesn't actually delete, but set the FK to NULL). Make it an answer and I'll accept!
It might depend on having `'by_reference' => false` on the `CollectionType`, haven't checked that.

Comment: @kiw true, EntityType doesn't allow editing contained entities but you could display a separate form via ajax (which is essentially, what I was proposing but apparently didn't transfer well) to edit the related entity separately. indexBy is probably a more robust and user-friendly solution though.

Comment: @Jakumi it did transfer, I just failed to acknowledge ;) I wanted to avoid ajax as its a fair bit more work and also spare the user submitting tons of individual forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since doctrine 2.1, it's possible to change [how associations are indexed](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/tutorials/working-with-indexed-associations.html). This will allow you to use the `id` as the collection key (as the field has to be unique):

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity="B", mappedBy="A", indexBy="id")
```

You might also need to enable [`orphanRemoval`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal) so that the data is actually removed instead of the relation just set to `null`.