# Not desired change of primary keys values when using symfony collection (embedded forms) with Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, collections, doctrine

At work I have an (old) project in Symfony 3.4 / Doctrine / mySQL in which I use a collection of embedded forms. A class A contains an arrayCollection (Doctrine OneToMany) of object B (ManyToOne).

In creation or editing, the input form of object A allows with an "Add" button to create / modify / delete embedded forms of object B. **It works as expected**.

Doctrine cascade (persist / remove and orphanRemoval) allow to automatically persist all modifications on object A (including new/modify/delete embedded object B).

I implemented all of this by strictly following the Symfony documentation (getters, setters on A and B, arrayCollections, Doctrine attributes). **Everything works fine**, add, modify, delete, but, for some reason I don't know, Doctrine (I think ) changes the primary key values ​​of the embedded objects (B) at each addition / deletion.

For example, A has 3 children in his collection:

1: id / value => 1 / val1

2: id / value => 2 / val2

3: id / value => 3 / val3

I delete # 2 and see in mySQL that:

1: id / value => 1 / val1

2: id / value => 2 / val3

val2 no longer exists, but val3 ends up with the id of val2: the id of val2 has changed !

In the Symfony profiler, Doctrine tab, I see that Doctrine (?) Has updated (SQL UPDATE) ) the id 2 to put val3 then deleted (SQL DELETE) the id 3. **This causes a change of id** and poses big problems of coherence with the foreign keys.

I expected id 2 to just be deleted without touching the rest (which doesn't change). I do not understand how it works.

Has anyone come across this case before and know how to make sure that the id's are preserved?

I searched Symfony and Doctrine, but so far I haven't found anything that helps me.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't see how updating a primary key is even possible at the SQL level.  Can you run `describe table` on whatever table is being victimized by this phenomenon and then update your question with the id column's definition?

Comment: Seems like [this could be a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64775433). There also was some discussion in an issue at github that went more in depth into the root cause but I cannot find it right now, although there are [some similar reports](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/4492) around.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved by removing anything that caused collection items to reorder in the view via twig, as well as removing sort sql orders (ASC, DESC) in annotations.

I also removed orphanRemoval and cascade (remove) annotation on the link between the parent and the children in the collection and by managing the removes by hand in the controller.

It's probably not the way to do but until better it works, the ids are no longer mixed.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent primary changes, you have to add a position property in your entity as described on [the documentation](https://github.com/ninsuo/symfony-collection/blob/d5e6cbc7c7dc1f0509631c9bb6094fead0f6c8f0/README.md#using-doctrine-and-a-position-explicitely-stored-in-a-field). Here is the example :

```
/**
  * @ORM\Column(name="position", type="integer")
  */
private $position;
```

Add the value in hidden field as below

```
$builder->add('position', HiddenType::class, [
   'attr' => [
      'class' => 'my-position',
    ],
]);
```

and add `position_field_selector` option on your javascript

```
$('.my-selector').collection({
   position_field_selector: '.my-position'
});
```